# Image XAML tag (Win8) not working with some paths

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

The Source attribute of the Image tag works only with the files which were added to the 'Assets' folder in the Solution Explorer.

I've got two files in the Assets directory: Logo.png and Logo2.png, but only Logo.png is added to 'Assets' in the Solution Explorer. This image works properly:

```
<Image Source="/Assets/Logo.png"/>
```

while this image doesn't show up:

```
<Image Source="/Assets/Logo2.png"/>
```

File paths like 'C:\Users\user\Pictures\img.jpg' don't work either.
Is it possible to access images which are not specified in the 'Assets' folder in the Solution Explorer?

EDIT:

Here is what I do:

1. Create new project in VS2012: Visual C# -> Windows Store -> Blank App (XAML)
2. Open MainPage.xaml
3. Choose Image from Toolbox and draw an image element in the Design mode
4. The only working value for the Source attribute is '/Assets/Logo.png'. These are not working: 'C:\images\img.jpg', '/Assets/Logo2.png', 'Project_name;component/Assets/Logo.png', 'Project_name;component/Assets/Logo2.png', etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here's what I've found out:

Windows Store Apps (Win8) have got limited access to files. So I can only use the files which are shipped with the application. However, it is possible to get the user's files if he chooses them in a file picker.

There is also a great sample [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/0f5d56ae-5e57-48e1-9cd9-993115b027b9).

Answer (score 3):

Here is the format you will want to use:

```
Project;component/ImagePath
```

Where Project is the name of the assembly (project in most cases) that you want to reference, and "component" specifies that the assembly being referred to is referenced from the local assembly.

So for the Logo2, you would do:

```
<Image Source="ImageDemo;component/Assets/Logo2.png" Name="custLogo"/>
```

Where "ImageDemo" is the project name and "Assets/Logo2.png" is the path inside project.

As for absolute paths, the following worked just fine for me:

```
<Image Source="C:\Images\001.jpg"></Image>
```

Comment: Especially ImageDemo is not implicitly the project name, but the name of the assembly containing the assets folder ;)

Comment: @MarcoKlein Right, which wouldn't that usually be the project name? It could be changed, but by default? Please correct me if I am wrong! :)

Comment: What about files with an absolute path? How can I load an image from the user's local machine?

Comment: @miloszmaki Try this: `<Image Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Assets/Logo2.jpg" Name="custLogo"/>`

Comment: I can't get it working in any way. Maybe I have to specify some options in project properties?

Comment: @miloszmaki Do you have to do this via XAML? This would be easier to do via C#.

Comment: Yes, I could do this using C#. Although something as simple as Source="C:\images\img.jpg" should work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21912/discussion-between-cc-inc-and-miloszmaki)

Comment: @CCInc Well, that's true. By default it's the project name, indeed. But I just wanted to mention that because it may be that someone wonders why the code may not work (In the case that project != assembly)